# Trouble Deploying to Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

On the beanstalk webpage I have it connected to a aws pipeline, and that is working okay. But when I deploy it, I am getting a severe health waring and this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TexF2.png)

Is there any way to fix this?

This is the package.js file.

```
{
  "name": "food4allkids",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "start":"node server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  }
  
}
```

This is the server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome to the Hone Page")
});

const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Hello")
});
```

This is the log that I am getting
https://pastebin.com/U8XjT235

Comment: Did you check the Cloud Watch logs?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure what I am looking at.

Comment: I can upload it, but I am not sure how to do that as well

Comment: Can you check the logs to get the exact error? If you can, I might be able to help

Comment: I used pastebin to post the log file